# How do I write tests for two-factor authentication?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, selenium, two-factor-authentication

I've recently implemented two-factor auth in a django application. I used a [third-party package](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth) for it, which is well-tested already. I want to write unit tests for my code, but it seems silly to test things which are really just their package. I feel really odd writing larger-scale selenium tests for the login process, especially e.g. scanning a QR code. Is the answer that if I'm not doing anything new with the code, just dropping in the existing library, that I can't effectively write tests for it? (because it's unnecessary?)

Comment: I am not trying to be a dick, but really the best person to answer that would be your project manager (or whatever is the equivalent in your shop). Personally I agree with you, but that is just one guy's opinion ... and opinions are off-topic for SO.

Comment: I asked him and he said something akin to "I have no idea"... would programmers.SE be better?

Comment: Then ask him about "scope of the project". Or have a chat with your QA guy(s).

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/174733/is-wrapping-a-third-party-code-the-only-solution-to-unit-test-its-consumers

Comment: You don't test external packages.The package will have its own unit tests,, but what are your unit tests? What about functional tests on your data, model and how it all interactions?